# Home Media Streaming Server

Tags: iphone, home-server, ipad, video-streaming

I'm looking for a Home Media Server which can stream videos to various devices including iPhone, iPad, Windows Machines, Android etc. I wouldn't want to install any client on any device; a web interface will be preferred. Also, it should be able to read videos of as many formats as possible and should stream by transcoding the resolution and format according to device's specifications.

I have a fairly powerful machine on which I'm free to install Windows 7 or Linux. The streaming will be done over a g/n WiFi router or Ethernet locally.

What is the suggested solution in my case?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.videolan.org/projects/vlma/

VLMa is an application to manage broadcasts of TV channels, received through digital terrestrial or satellite ways. Its interface is provided as a web-site written in Java. It is also capable of streaming audio and video files. VLMa consists of a deamon (called VLMad) and a web interface (called VLMaw).

How to setup it: http://www.videolan.org/projects/vlma/doc/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://tversity.com/?

Answer (score 0):

The [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) player has capability to play all kind of formats. Also it can play streaming data. And it has built-in media outcasting feature. It's not a server though.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Livebox](http://livebox.co.in)? With Livebox, you can stream anyhere, home or to the internet.